# Mockito mocking get methods from the database services

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a getBy() method after adding an element by a mocked service add.

This is what I have:

```
FeedItem feedItem = feedServiceTested.createFeedItem("Text Test", "Category Test", "Author Test");
        Mockito.verify(feedRepository).add(feedItem);

        Mockito.verify(feedRepository).findAllByCategory("Category Test");
```

However I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
feedRepository.findAllByCategory(
    "Category Test"
);
-> at ie.cit.adf.services.FeedServiceImplTest.testSearchFeedItemsByCategory(FeedServiceImplTest.java:55)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at ie.cit.adf.services.FeedServiceImpl.createFeedItem(FeedServiceImpl.java:44)

    at ie.cit.adf.services.FeedServiceImplTest.testSearchFeedItemsByCategory(FeedServiceImplTest.java:55)
```

Any idea how to mock this findAllByCategory()?

Here are the 2 classes:

Repository:

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public class JdbcFeedRepository implements FeedRepository {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private FeedItemsMapper feedItemsMapper = new FeedItemsMapper();

    public JdbcFeedRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public FeedItem findById(String feedItemId) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "SELECT ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, AUTHOR FROM FEEDITEMS WHERE ID=?", 
            feedItemsMapper, 
            feedItemId
        );
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedItem> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, AUTHOR FROM FEEDITEMS", 
            feedItemsMapper
        );
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedItem> findAllByCategory(String category) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, AUTHOR FROM FEEDITEMS WHERE CATEGORY=?", 
                feedItemsMapper,
                category
            );
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedItem> findAllByAuthor(String author) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, AUTHOR FROM FEEDITEMS WHERE AUTHOR=?", 
            feedItemsMapper,
            author
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void add(FeedItem feedItem) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(
            "INSERT INTO FEEDITEMS VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
            feedItem.getId(),
            feedItem.getText(),
            feedItem.getCategory(),
            feedItem.getAuthor()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String feedItemId) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM FEEDITEMS WHERE ID=?", feedItemId);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the currently logged in Author.
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    private String getCurrentUser() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    }

}

class FeedItemsMapper implements RowMapper<FeedItem> {
    @Override
    public FeedItem mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
        feedItem.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
        feedItem.setText(rs.getString("TEXT"));
        feedItem.setCategory(rs.getString("CATEGORY"));
        feedItem.setAuthor(rs.getString("AUTHOR"));
        return feedItem;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
public class FeedServiceImpl implements FeedService {

    private FeedRepository repo;

    public FeedServiceImpl(FeedRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedItem get(String feedItemId) {
        return repo.findById(feedItemId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedItem> getAllFeedItems() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedItem> getAllFeedItemsByCategory(String category) {
        return repo.findAllByCategory(category);
    }

    @Override
    public List<FeedItem> getAuthorFeedItems(String author) {
        return repo.findAllByAuthor(author);
    }

    @Override
    public FeedItem createFeedItem(String text, String category, String author) {
        FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
        feedItem.setText(text);
        feedItem.setCategory(category);
        feedItem.setAuthor(author);

        repo.add(feedItem);

        return feedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String feedItemId) {
        repo.delete(feedItemId);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your test looks basically sensible.  Can you show the method being tested - feedServiceTested.createFeedItem ?

Comment: check the original post, updated.

Comment: Still doesn't include the createFeedItem method, which is the one being exercised in the test code.

Comment: Check again, i have added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code never calls:

```
feedRepository.findAllByCategory("Category Test");
```

But you added a verifier for it. Mockito verify ensures the method is called one time in your test. When this did not happen its complains with an exception.

Your test calls:

```
feedServiceTested.createFeedItem(...)
```

Which only calls the following methods on repo:

```
add(feedItem)
```

Which is your first verify. So at the moment it seems your code did not use findAllByCategory and so does the verify throws this exception.

Or is there a call in FeedItem to the repo? Then please provide the code for this class too.

Comment: And I guess your class FeedItem ist just a stupid java object without any logic or calls to any other class? Just getter and setter?

Comment: That is correct, the only logic would be setting an id in the object using: UUID.randomUUID().toString();

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. You are never calling findAllByCategory in the execution of your UnitTest (as far as we have the code snippet from it), why would you expect that the second verify should not throw an exception?

Comment: How would I perform that then? Would I do this:

`FeedItem feedItem = feedServiceTested.createFeedItem("Text Test", "Category Test", "Author Test");
  Mockito.verify(feedRepository).add(feedItem);

  List<FeedItem> feedItems = feedServiceTested.getAllFeedItemsByCategory("Category Test");
  Mockito.verify(feedRepository).findAllByCategory("Category Test");
  assertThat(feedItems.size(), equalTo(1));`

Doesnt seem to work?

Comment: You need to add a behaviour what your mock should return because a mockito mock returns always the default value, means for objects null and for primitives 0,'0', false. So add `when(feedRepository.findAllByCategory("Category Test")).thenReturn(feedItemArrayList)` before the call to feedServiceTested.getAllFeedItemsByCategory.